# JS: Changing variable wont apply on next

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this:

```
$('#albumPhotoNext').live('click', function () {
var currentDate = '<?php echo $grab["date"]; ?>';
    $.ajax({
    url: "photo.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { currentDate : currentDate },
    success: function(r){
    currentDate = r.date;
    }
    });
});
```

I want to set currentDate for the r.date, on success, so next time you click on #albumPhotoNext, the currentDate is the r.date.

Right now it gives me the $grab["date"]; when i click, no matter if i did set the currentDate to r.date or not.

I only want to have $grab["date"]; as "default" if it hasnt been set to r.date

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define `currentDate` in a scope that is reachable from the scope you want to use it. Currently, `currentDate` is local to the event handler, so only the code inside the event handler can see the value and it gets **reassigned** to `$grab["date"]` every time the handler is called.
Define it in some scope above, e.g. in the document ready handler:

```
$(function() {  
    var currentDate = '<?php echo $grab["date"]; ?>';

    $('#albumPhotoNext').live('click', function () {       
        $.ajax({
        url: "photo.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { currentDate : currentDate },
        success: function(r){
        currentDate = r.date;
        }
        });
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`currentDate` is a **local** variable, so its value gets reset every invocation.

You will need to make the variable exist in an outer scope for your changes to persist.

The easy way of doing this:

```
$(function() {
   var currentDate = '<?php echo $grab["date"]; ?>';
   $('#albumPhotoNext').live('click', function () {
      $.ajax({
         url: "photo.php",
         type: "post",
         data: { 'currentDate' : currentDate },
         success: function(r){
            currentDate = r.date;
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in a slightly different way. Instead of assigning "currentDate" to a variable, just use another jQuery selector to set the current date on the page itself.

```
$.('#albumPhotoNext').live('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: "photo.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { currentDate : currentDate },
    success: function(r){
        $.('#dateOnPage').html(r.date);
    }
    });
});
```